# Path planning for hector_slam

Tags: ros, rplidar, ros-kinetic, hector, pathplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i'm using view_hectorSlam.launch file for visualization and i just want to add path planning feature to this launch file. I only use rplidar connected to ttyUSB0 on Ubuntu 16.04 with ros-kinetic and i just want to see a path from rplidar position to desired position. Glad if you can help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292215/path-planning-for-hector_slam/) by [frozt](https://answers.ros.org/users/35445/frozt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try this [hector_navigation](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_navigation),you can focus on hector_exploration_planner

---

Originally posted by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) with karma: 138 on 2018-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0